# IntelliSense Not Working in MS SQL Server Management Studio2014

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL 2014 and VS 2013. 
When i connect Management Studio to local database then IntelliSense works fine, but if i connect remote database of 2014 then IntelliSense  doesn't work, previously i was using Management Studio 2008 with this IntelliSense  was working fine, but with 2014 it doesn't work. 
Am I need to install any other tool or something to make it work?

I already changed setting as bellow

[image: Hear My SQL Management 2014 Settings]

[image: SQL Studio 2014 Version Info]

Comment: reinstall the software -(

Comment: This usually happens when there is a mismatch of SQL Versions. Run `SELECT name, @@VERSION, compatibility_level from sys.databases WHERE name = 'DatabaseNameHere'` in the database without intellisense. What do you get?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP1) (KB3167392) - 12.0.4457.0 (X64)  || compatibility_level = 100

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible causes. You may first try refreshing the cache by

1. Hit Ctrl+Shift+R, or
2. Go to Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache

If IntelliSense is still not working, then make sure you have IntelliSense enabled. 
To check this from the T-SQL Query editor window of current database,

1. Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Transact-SQL -> General -> IntelliSense
2. Go to Query -> IntelliSense should be selected
3. Also verify that the T-SQL Editor does not launch in SQLCMD Mode, go to

Tools -> Options -> Query Execution -> SQL Server -> General

Make sure

> By default, open new queries in SQLCMD mode

is unchecked.
Or, Go to Query ->

> SQLCMD Mode

should not be selected

If IntelliSense is still not working. Get latest update and start re-installing is the best bet.

Comment: Reinstall is not at all good option man, by the way i tried all your option still no luck.

Comment: I have the same problem, but a little wierder. I connect SSMS to a 2016 sql server (v 13.0.1601.5) and intellisense does not work, but when I connect it to another sql server 2016, same version, there it works!

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with 2014. You can apply cumulative update 1 for SQL 2014 to fix it

See link below:

[kb2897539](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2897539)

**Edit** This was not the solution in this case but I will keep this answer as it may be an issue for others.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to (have your employer) buy SQL Prompt from Red Gate. Even when it is "working", SQL Server's built in Intellisense is barely usable.